# Diablo 3, loot system, PS4

Tags: diablo-iii-console

So me and a friend have been playing on the PS4 Diablo 3 for a week or so, and he started before me and was a higher level, and I was a lower level, but then I passed him. Now were both in the paragon levels (I'm still higher level) all of my armor is legendary, in sets, and I have an ancient weapon, he only has a couple, I'm way weaker than him (I'm a demon Hunter and he's a wizard) but 8/10 of the loot goes to me 90% of the time and I get all of the legendaries and when he gets one finally I  still also get one. I know the loot system follows the levels and the class. And I also know the game favors the lower levels, or weaker. So why is this happening? Is there any way to change it?
(Sorry if this is really stupid but I honestly can't find anything)

Comment: Loot drops are individual, not party based, and there is nothing you can do to influence them to your favor. I also don't believe the game "favors" anyone because of lower levels.

Comment: This is anecdotal, but ive been playing seasonal (S10) with a buddy, both at paragon 800+, and he has 8 primals while i have 0. If this game wants you to be sad, it will make you sad, and you will get everything except what you want, all the time. Its brutal, but makes it all the more satisfying when you DO get what you want. Then you think, *oh its not so random, i should try harder!* but 4 hours later youre back where you started, cursing the game, and Kadala, and Kanai, and the gods of RNG.

Answer (score 3):

VanBuzzKill nailed it on the head, but let's go a little in depth for an answer:

Loot drops on a per-player basis. Let's say, for instance, that you and your friend are fighting the Butcher. Once you kill him, great and bountiful loot and blood spill around the arena. The loot drops that you see will not be what your friend sees. For you, perhaps a Manald Heal ring drops; for your friend, perhaps a Unity set ring drops.

There is very little you can do to influence this, as there are no items or mechanics that can game the system like this.

The only way the game favors a lower level player in co-op is by upping their skills/damage numbers a bit until they reach a certain level. This has nothing to do with item drop rates.

Comment: I cant find a better source than [this wiki blurb](https://www.diablowiki.net/Magic_find) at the moment, but doesn't Magic Find stat increase item drops (per player), and slightly raise odds of legendaries? Linked post says its a minor benefit, most people just push higher torments / rifts, but it might explain a little of OP's discrepancy with his friend if he has high MF.

Comment: High Magic Find seems like a rare thing to have though, and would need a specific gear set it would see. Besides, only 10% of a characters magic find amount contributes to legendary drop rates, so their magic find would need to be enormous.

Comment: Agreed, makes sense